# Should I store an open file handle in a logger class for later use?

Tags: php, logging

I'm writing a simple Logger class that writes logs to file. My `log` method looks like this:

```
    public function log($level, $message)
    {
        $f = fopen($this->logFile, 'a');
        flock($f, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
        fprintf($f, '[%s] %s: %s', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $level, $message);
        flock($f, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($f);
    }
```

My question is simple. Should I store the open file handle `$f` and just lock/unlock it whenever I'm writing to it or should I open and close the file every time I call the log method?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I would open the log file when you initialise and close when you leave php.

Answer (score 1):

How many times are you "logging" within the same script?  If the answer to that is more than one then ideally you should be optimising your script by making all your logs in as fewer writes as possible.

The next question is how resource hungry is your script?  Presumably (as it's the most common) the scenario is within the confines of a web server?  In that case - you potentially have simultaneous requests to the same script (which is why you are locking in the first place?) - you don't want to be in a position where one request is hanging - waiting for the first instance of the script to release the lock.

My approach would be to keep a handle on the file to the minimum length of time possible as it's an obvious bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to open / close it. But it's PHP I don't think the difference between has a big impact.

If you want to be sure to not have leak just open -> write -> close

Comment: I could close it in a __destruct method, but I thought it would make a difference...

Comment: You can do that, but in my opinion the best way to do is to open a resource only when you need it and close it when you don't need it anymore